# Convert float to string containing all digits

Tags: floating-point, rust

In Rust, I can convert a float to a string using `println!` or `.to_string()`, but it will only print the necessary digits to be lossless. How can I get *all* the digits of a float? For example `0.1f32` should be converted to `"0.100000001490116119384765625"`.

Comment: *it will only print the necessary digits to be lossless* — wouldn't that be "all of the digits" then?

Comment: @Shepmaster - No - I assume the OP means lossless in the sense of uniquely mappable back to the original float.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Due to ambiguities of English, I cannot tell whether Shepmaster means what you suggest or the opposite. The words in their comment could mean that all the necessary digits to be lossless satisfy OP’s request for all the digits (if somebody believed a floating-point number was an approximate and hence producing all the digits for it to be lossless was effectively producing the number) or it could mean that producing all the digits is necessary to produce the necessary digits to be lossless (because if you do not produce all the digits, there is some loss…

Comment: … in the sense that the printed value does not equal the represented value, so it has lost some of the value).

Comment: @Shepmaster: Per IEEE-754, each floating-point number represents one number exactly. For example, in IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point, the least non-zero number represented is 2^-149, which, when represented in decimal, has 149 digits after the decimal point. Since it has 44 leading zeros, it has 105 significant digits. Producing all the digits needed to be lossless is merely (in general) rounding to a decimal numeral, not producing the actual digits of the represented number.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
format!("{:.51}", i).trim_right_matches(|c| c == '0' || c == '.').to_string();
```

It's a little crap in that you need to specify in advance the maximum number of digits necessary, and I'm not 100% sure about the 51 (for `f32` - it will be much more for `f64`).

Also `trim_right_matches()` returns a `&str` and then `to_string()` makes a new `String` out of it, which is suboptimal. You could do it better just by `truncate()`ing the `String` returned by `format!()`.

Comment: Since this answer is not correct, you ought to delete it before the down votes start.

Comment: Left it because I was going to fix it.

Comment: For future reference, you can delete, edit, and undelete.